# gmail inbox actions are exclusive?

Tags: javascript, html, gmail, inbox

This question may get negative to oblivion as I don't know how important this is. But I made a fast search and couldn't find anything about other major e-mail providers developing those [inbox actions](https://developers.google.com/gmail/actions/?hl=pt-es).

I'm wondering if anyone knows if that's something I should use only for e-mails sent to gmail or others will eventually implement that functionality?

Comment: i don't think others will use the same code even if they eventually offer such a feature. i would include links and the script for now...

Comment: it looks like an initiative from schema.org. Just like w3c.org creates docs for html, schema.org creates docs for search engines and that sort of stuff. I mean, maybe everyone will use the same code, provided by schema.org.